# Looking for a Manga/Manhwa leaves his world and goes to a world where he has powers

Tags: story-identification, manga, supernatural, isekai

I don't remember the title, but the details I can go into. The MC is approached by this woman and he gets flashbacks like he met her before. He is transported to this different world and everyone is in a classroom. And they all have to open a box/satchel that they have that represents what their standing is. The MC is also able to see everyone else’s stats and abilities. And they are task with escaping this room and since he has done this before he knows there will be a zombie attack and he has to escape through the hole in the ground to get to the second story of the school.

Comment: I have a few points i would like clarification on. You say the main character had 'done this before', is this because this was him going back in time, or that he has been transported to a different world before? How is this world different? Is it just that people have powers, or are there other races like dwarfs and elves? Can everyone see everyone else's stats, or is that a power of the Main Character? What power does the Main Character have? Do they get stronger, and if so, how?

Comment: Also, I believe the Supernatural tag is meant for the television show Supernatural.  Does this mean that you are looking for a manga version of Supernatural where the brothers get sent to another world? or did you just mean that there were elements that were supernatural in it?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be looking for *The Second Coming of Gluttony* by Ro Yujin and Ahn Jonghyeok

> He was an addict, a loser, a despicable human being. But, one fleeting dream that may not have been a dream at all reawakens his once-lost senses. Possessing a very unique ability, he would use that, and the dream, to forge his path in the world now known as the Lost Paradise.

**The MC is approached by this woman and he gets flashbacks like he met her before.**

[image: MC approached by the woman]

**And they all have to open a box/satchel that they have that represents what their standing is**

Most people don't get a satchel, some of them have the bronze one, a few the silver grade and the MC has gold.

[image: The satchel]

**The MC is also able to see everyone else’s stats and abilities.**

[image: Status windows]

**And they are task with escaping this room**

[image: Escape mission]

**He has to escape through the hole in the ground to get to the second story of the school.**

[image: The hole]